# Is this normal/fine for a pci-e x16 slot?

Tags: motherboard, gpu, pci-express

I was in the middle of cleaning the dust build-up in my PC and when I took the gpu out carefully and got the gpu out. I noticed this

https://imgur.com/a/4YTvikF
[image]

[image]

This is the whole pci-e x16 slot area /w different angles.

https://imgur.com/a/1n79kss
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Look at the red marked area. There's some white/yellow like markings/patterns or something like it came from the gpu pci-e. I'm genuinely scared if I broke off something. Can this be cleaned using a brush or some sort.

And will it affect anything? Break something? I'm don't know anything about the motherboard. FYI it isn't bent the retention clip still works fine. Or maybe I'm just paranoid.

Comment: Maybe I'm just missing it, but I don't see what you're referring to.  Your slot looks normal to me.

Comment: Zoom in closely there's like markings of somesort.

Comment: Yeah, I did.  It's not really clear to me what you're calling markings.  To me it looks normal, maybe someone else will chime in.  Sorry, guess that's not really helpful :-/

Comment: It's probably just dust no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* I can see what you are getting at. When you zoom in there is a regular pattern down the center of the PCIe slot
[image]

Given that it is between each pin I think that it is an artefact of the injection moulding and contact insertion in the plastic. It has a shine to it that doesn't suggest dust but instead is more likely to be a smooth plastic surface with a slight angle to it.

There's nothing particularly "wrong" in any of your images, they're just normal PCIe slots.

I don't think you broke anything, nor do you need to poke a brush down in there.

Comment: Thank you thank you, i also noticed this on my other pc.